# logback-spring file not loading from consul in spring boot 3 and spring cloud 2022.0.2

Tags: spring-boot

logback-spring
file not loading in latest spring boot 3
config: http://${spring.cloud.consul.host}:${spring.cloud.consul.port}/v1/kv/${spring.cloud.consul.config.prefixes}/logback-spring.xml?raw=true&xml

the spring.cloud.consul.config.prefix is changed to spring.cloud.consul.config.prefixes
and the logback-spring file not get loaded

I used this property config: http://${spring.cloud.consul.host}:${spring.cloud.consul.port}/v1/kv/${spring.cloud.consul.config.prefixes}/logback-spring.xml?raw=true&xml
but its not working for spring boot3